# How can i get the value from a textclock

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

In my app i have a textclock displaying the current hour and i want to when i click a button to get the value from the textclock and put it in a string variable. I have it like this:

```
TextClock time = (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.horas);
horas = time.getText().toString();
```

And in my layout the textclock is like this:

```
<TextClock
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/horas"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/space2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

But with this it returns an empty value.

Comment: That should work, as long as you're calling it after the `TextClock` has been laid out; i.e., after it is visible on-screen.

Comment: Thank you man with your coment i have realized that the code wasnt in the correct place :D

Comment: if you solved it, please post an answer and mark it as the correct answer so it does not appear in the unsolved question anymore

Answer (score -1):

This should do:

```
time.getFormat12Hour();
```

or:

```
time.getFormat24Hour();
```

you would have a working clock as this:

[Image shows a working digital clock which matches system time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vkXF.png)